Power Automate Flow to Send Sign-off/Vote Email via Outlook once Work Item in Azure DevOps reaches specific State
I greatly appreciate any help and direction.
I would like to setup a flow in Power Automate that will send an email via Outlook (ideally one with Outlook's 'Vote'ng setting configured) whenever a work item in my Azure Devops project advances to a specific 'State' (aka 'Ready for Testing Signoff'). The idea is that when testing is finished on a work item, I would like the 'Assigned To' OR an email field in the work item to receive an email in order to sign-off on the work complete. Another ideal step would be for the Azure Devops work item to be updated on the response (but I'll take what I can get ).
Important note, not all the 'Assigned To' members have access to the ADO project, so it would be ideal if the 'State' would update via the email response back (or perhaps a better method to do this via a MS Form?).
Is this possible and how would I go about creating this in a flow? Any ideas or recommendations are welcome, I'm very new to this process so I appreciate your details and patience. Thanks, all!
So far I've attempted to create a flow with both Azure DevOps & Outlook connected, but need assistance in how to fill the 'to' in a email using custom code + be able to pull any fields from ADO.
I'm also unaware how to code the Outlook message for 'Vote'ng or devise a method separately for the 'approval' side.

